# AVD Not Working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to open my avd it says everything under the line and after that It opens it up and all it says is android and nothing else

C:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86
emulator: device fd:976
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: VT feature is not enabled, HAXM not working.
You might want to check your BIOS/UEFI settings and/or system manual on how to enable.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.1', last version '24.4.1'

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 0):

[Down load the SDK intel x86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11r4L.png)

Then go to SDK-> extras-> intel-> Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager ->

Then Install the intelhaxm-android and Restart your pc

I hope it will be work....